# How to connect ready-made scripts in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a ready-made layout, it has scripts (spoilers, sliders, parallax). I want to transfer this to React, but I don’t quite understand how to connect ready-made scripts, before everything was written from scratch. For example, one of the scripts: parallx on the mouse, it was added during the layout process

```
class MousePRLX {
constructor(props, data = null) {
    let defaultConfig = {
        init: true,
        logging: true,
    }
    this.config = Object.assign(defaultConfig, props);
    if (this.config.init) {
        const paralaxMouse = document.querySelectorAll('[data-prlx-mouse]');
        if (paralaxMouse.length) {
            this.paralaxMouseInit(paralaxMouse);
        } 
    }
}
paralaxMouseInit(paralaxMouse) {
    paralaxMouse.forEach(el => {
        const paralaxMouseWrapper = el.closest('[data-prlx-mouse-wrapper]');

        
        const paramСoefficientX = el.dataset.prlxCx ? +el.dataset.prlxCx : 100;
        
        const paramСoefficientY = el.dataset.prlxCy ? +el.dataset.prlxCy : 100;
        
        const directionX = el.hasAttribute('data-prlx-dxr') ? -1 : 1;
        
        const directionY = el.hasAttribute('data-prlx-dyr') ? -1 : 1;
        
        const paramAnimation = el.dataset.prlxA ? +el.dataset.prlxA : 50;


        
        let positionX = 0, positionY = 0;
        let coordXprocent = 0, coordYprocent = 0;

        setMouseParallaxStyle();

    
        if (paralaxMouseWrapper) {
            mouseMoveParalax(paralaxMouseWrapper);
        } else {
            mouseMoveParalax();
        }

        function setMouseParallaxStyle() {
            const distX = coordXprocent - positionX;
            const distY = coordYprocent - positionY;
            positionX = positionX + (distX * paramAnimation / 1000);
            positionY = positionY + (distY * paramAnimation / 1000);
            el.style.cssText = `transform: translate3D(${directionX * positionX / (paramСoefficientX / 10)}%,${directionY * positionY / (paramСoefficientY / 10)}%,0);`;
            requestAnimationFrame(setMouseParallaxStyle);
        }
        function mouseMoveParalax(wrapper = window) {
            wrapper.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                const offsetTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
                if (offsetTop >= window.scrollY || (offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) >= window.scrollY) {
                    
                    const parallaxWidth = window.innerWidth;
                    const parallaxHeight = window.innerHeight;
                    
                    const coordX = e.clientX - parallaxWidth / 2;
                    const coordY = e.clientY - parallaxHeight / 2;
                    
                    coordXprocent = coordX / parallaxWidth * 100;
                    coordYprocent = coordY / parallaxHeight * 100;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: can you provide any one of your script, So I can understand what thing do you want to related with React.

Comment: @BhaveshDaswani I added one of the scripts that is already built in at the layout stage

Comment: you can't, these scripts does direct DOM manipulation but in react you can't do that (not easy). Look for react port of that library.

Comment: @bogdanoff Unfortunately this is not a library. I'll think about it, thanks for the reply